# How to programmatically tell if my app is being debugged?

Tags: android, debugging

I'm looking for a way to tell if my app is running under the debugger or running "normally", under Android Studio..

These two cases are
1. Run the app by clicking the "Run app" button (green arrow)
2. Run the app by clicking the "Debug app" button (gear icon)

I would like to output more verbose diagnostics (using Log.*) while debugging.
I tried checking BuildConfig.DEBUG but that is TRUE in either case. I suspect this is because Android Studio signs the app with the *Debug Certificate* in both cases.

**Does anyone know how to distinguish these two cases at runtime?**

Comment: When running your app from android studio you are always in "Debug mode" which is why you always see `BuildConfig.DEBUG` as true, this flag turns false when you sign your apk. There is no way to distinguish between Run or Debug

Comment: how about case when you've attached a debugger? Should logger change its behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

typically one would check for `BuildConfig.DEBUG` (or a `boolean` variable holding it) and then log:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {Log.d("SomeActivity", "debug message");}
```

see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig)... most relevant for debugging is build-config `debuggable` `true/false`.

the `run` button does not start the debugger; no matter the build-config (it just skips all breakpoints).

in multi-module projects, one should check with:

```
(getContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0
```

to tell them apart, two build types need to be configured:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            ...
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}
```

and to precisely answer the question, there even is one method called [isDebuggerConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug#isDebuggerConnected()), which would always return `false` when hitting the `run` button (no matter the build-config).

Comment: Nope, no cigar. BOTH BuildConfig and ApplicationInfo flags return true .irrespective of starting by "Run" or "Debug".

Comment: @DontPanic extended my answer and also found the desired method. how about a cigar now?

Comment: isDebuggerConnected() worked PERFECTLY! Thanks for the research.

Answer (score 0):

**"Run app"**

This will install the application into your device/emulator

**"Debug app"**

This will enable you to debug function by placing the break points into your code.
which means you will be able to stop execution of code at that point and debug it line by line. To know more about debugging in android see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/)

Both the application are debug applications.
To know more about build type please read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is how to distinguish between the two at run-time.